# Associating Symbol Names with .PLT Entries

Tags: ida, elf, got, plt

Doing some messing around with ELF (of both the x86 and ARM varieties).

Associating symbol names with entries in the `.got` section is straightforward.  Find the `.got` section, find the relocation section `.rel.plt`/`.rela.plt` whose `.sh_info` contains the index of the `.got`, and find the symbol section `.dynsym` that contains the symbol names.

Everything lines up nicely between these sections, and I can accurately assign symbol names to entries in the `.got`.

However, I also want names for the stubs in the `.plt` section.  A rough percentage of the time, symbols for the `.plt` can be inferred based on the ordering of `.got` symbols, and an offset from the base of the `.plt` section.  For whatever reason, occasionally this is not the case.

Binutils `objdump` can accurately generate them for x86, and IDA can accurately generate them for x86 and ARM (both without `-g` debugging symbols).  How are these generated?

In the case of IDA, I could reasonably assume there's some advanced logic going on based on interpretation of the instructions in the `.plt`, but I know that must not be the case for `objdump`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [this thread](http://www.sourceware.org/ml/binutils/2004-04/msg00469.html). Basically, they rely on the fact that the order of PLT relocations matches the order of the stubs in `.plt` section, and the stubs are all of the same size.

On some platforms you can also use `st_value` of the symbol entry in the dynamic symbol table.

IDA indeed usually does not rely on the order of symbols/relocations but checks the actual instructions in the stub.